# Get the filename with complete path on Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, custom-activity

I'm implementing `IDotNetActivity` while working on `CustomActivity`.

I want to read a file name that exists on input dataset at folder path `adftutorial/customactivityinput/abc.txt`, update some text and finally copy the result at output dataset `adftutorial/customactivityoutput/xyz.txt`.

while reading file `abc.txt` I'm getting `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` occurred in `MyDotNetActivity.dll`.

I'm looking help on some method which could give me complete path like `<AzureCloutDirectory> + filename`.

Please advise what is the best approach or the way to load text file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give some more information (code) how do you access to the blob/blob information you need.

I can tell you that when you get blobs with `BlobResultSegment blobList = inputClient.ListBlobsSegmented(...)` method and iterate each one with:

```
        foreach (IListBlobItem listBlobItem in blobResult.Results)
        {
            var cloudBlockBlob = listBlobItem as CloudBlockBlob;
            ... // Your code here
        }
```

you can access complete path  + filename with

`cloudBlockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri` property

== "AzureCloudDirectory/ContainerName/yourFile.txt"

Kind regards!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It worked fine. I do have another question what is the best way to read particular file in stream.

Comment: @SandeepChoudhary which stream? (Get file by its name?)

Comment: I have to take input file, make some modifications and then finally upload the file. I need an alternate to File.Create(outputFile) or below code.                       using (Stream fOut = File.Create(outputFile))
                    {
                        Stream s= ld.GetInputStream();
                        Streams.PipeAll(s, fOut);
                    }

Comment: Just look my code up in the post. While you are in foreach, you iterate blobs , so you have possibility to to download blob like this `string file = cloudBlockBlob.DownloadText();`, but if you have binary files you should use `byte[] byteArray = new byte[cloudBlockBlob.Properties.Length];
 cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToByteArray(byteArray, 0);` or even `var StreamBlob = cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToFile();` or `var StreamBlob = cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStream();`. You can choose what suits you the best. Feel free to upvote if this answer is OK. Kind regards!